what is the correct way to "correct" the Hire record without payroll impact, for ADP and CDP respectively
For example, attached employee has a Hire record effective on Aug 7, then business added another Data Change record with the same effective date Aug 7 for him, since there was a re-organization on the business side that resulted in this organizational data change.
we are trying to make id of an employee that resigned then again rehired by the same organisation
